# How to send parameters from datatable to controller Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatable, datatables, laravel-8

I have a datatable in my blade view Laravel, I user click the blue button it will open new page and show all task with same user_id as clicked  before

[image]

I'm trying to pass `user_id` value to controller. I have do this following code

My routes

```
 Route::get('/detail/{user_id}', [PageController::class, 'UserTask'])->name('user.task');
```

My datatable code in blade file

```
 $(function() {
        var user_id = $(this).data('user_id'); //have different value from each rows
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        var table = $('.data-table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{{ route('user.task') }}" + '/' + user_id,

            columns: [{
                    data: 'DT_RowIndex',
                    name: 'DT_RowIndex',
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false,
                },
                {
                    data: 'title',
                    name: 'title',
                    orderable: false,
                },
                {
                    data: 'content',
                    name: 'content',
                    orderable: false,
                    visible: false,
                },
                {
                    data: 'progress',
                    name: 'progress'
                },
                {
                    data: 'status',
                    name: 'status'
                },
                {
                    data: 'target_selesai',
                    name: 'target_selesai'
                },
                {
                    data: 'action',
                    name: 'action',
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false
                },
            ]
        });
    });
```

my controller

```
  public function UserTask($user_id)
    {


        $data = Post::where('user_id', $user_id)->latest()->get();
        return Datatables::of($data)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('action', function ($row) {
                $id = $row->id;
                // $this->actionButton($row->id);
                $btn = ' <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="' . $id . '" data-original-title="Detail" class="btn btn-success mr-1 btn-sm detailProduct"><span class="fas fa-info"></span></a>';

                return $btn;
            })->addColumn('target_selesai', function ($row) {
                //...
            })
            ->addColumn('progress', function ($row) {
                //...
            })->addColumn('status', function ($row) {
               //...
            })
            ->rawColumns(['action', 'progress', 'status'])
            ->make(true);


        return view('detail');
    }
```

But, it will return error `Missing required parameter for [Route: user.task]`
If I remove all the parameter {user_id}, from routes, ajax routes, and change the

```
 public function UserTask($user_id)
    {
        $data = Post::where('user_id', $user_id)->latest()->get();
```

into

```
public function UserTask()
    {
        $data = Post::where('user_id', 1000000002)->latest()->get();
```

The program will works perfectly, how can I pass the `user_id` value from datatable to controller?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `"{{ route('user.task') }}" + '/' + user_id` as `route()` function renders the route in the server while you're trying to change it in the client side. Send the `user_id` via as data with ajax and retrieve it using `request()->get('user_id')`

Comment: how can I send the user_id as data with ajax?

Comment: Check [this](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/jquery/jquery-ajax-method#:~:text=ajax()%20method%20allows%20you,request.)

Comment: I got this

ajax: {
    "type": "POST",
    "url": "{{ route('user.task') }}",
    "data": {
       myData: 'This is my data.'
      
    },
What should I use to replace inside ```data{ }``` ?

Comment: `data:{ user_id: user_id }`

Comment: The error dissapear, but my datatable didn't show any data. what should I do?